# How to order the collection by a nested relation Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Been stuck for a while now even after reading docs & examples.
I am trying to get a collection ordered by price. The price attribute is nested in a relation that needs to be accessed by the user ID and the service type ID.
Here is the relation between tables in which there is the criteria I need to use for sorting:

**EDIT** 
Here is something working thanks to @jarek :-)

```
$users_available = $users_available->join('stypes_4_user', function($join)use($stype)
                              {
                                $join->on('user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                      ->where('service_type_id', '=', $stype);
                              })
                            ->orderBy('price', 'desc')->get();
```

**EDIT 2**
If you ever end up struggling after using a `->select('*')` after the join and not being able to access your model's methods make sure you are calling `'yourtablename.*'` and not just `'*'`. read more here:
http://jpcamara.com/selecting-carefully-laravel-joins/

Comment: So do you want by any chance something like pagination, so the query needs to be ordered? Because, you know, something you asked previously - sorting collection is another feature. But you use it on already fetched result (thus sorting a collection..).

Comment: Thanks, well now that I discovered pagination yes it is basically the output I need but with on top of it the results sorted by price. I have filters in my view that should reorganize the results: example: sort by price high to low. 
Excuse my noobism first time I have to deal with that.

Comment: So you need `join`, there's no other way to order by field of the related table. Try and let me know, if you can't do it I will show you.

Comment: Awesome I managed to make it work! Thanks I updated my question with the code! ;) Just now it won't divide the price by the duration, it says division by zero. I am wondering if I should not add a column with that info already calculated? What do you think?
Also the pagination thing, do you recommend using it basically it will display a specific number of replies per page.

Comment: I would add `select` (or pass array to `get`) so you fetch only main table fields, unless you want the other fields too. You can add division and whatever you want, but probably with `orderByRaw` or `DB::raw(..)` for that.

Comment: Awesome thanks! If you want to post the code I can validate your answer otherwise I will create an answer lol :-)